# How to Delay MessageDialogBox in Java?

Tags: java, swing

So in this chunk of code:

```
//Actions performed when an event occurs.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        String command = event.getActionCommand();

        //If btnConvertDocuments is clicked, the FileConverter method is called and the button is then disabled [so as to prevent duplicates].
        if (command.equals("w"))
        {
            new Thread(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    FileConverter fc = new FileConverter();

                }
             }).start();
            btnConvertDocuments.setEnabled(false);
            //Validation message ensuring completion of the step.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Step 1 Complete!", "Validation", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
```

It seems like the message dialog window pop-ups way too fast, before the FileConverter method isn't even finished being called. I was wondering if the placement of JOptionPane was correct, or if there was a way to delay a message until the method finished processing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

Have a look here, [java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

```
SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {
        FileConverter fc = new FileConverter();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void done() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Step 1 Complete!", "Validation", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
};
```

Comment: Is SwingWorker not a pre-built class in swing? When I tried to use it in eclipse, it gave me a compiler error stating SwingWorker cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: It has been included in Swing since Java 6.

Comment: Yeah I have the latest version, but I still can't import SwingWorker.

Comment: Perhaps you have to set your compiler level up to 6

Comment: @oliholz I changed the jre to java 6, but the highest compiler level I can go is 1.6?

Comment: that should work [see here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/version-6-141920.html)

Comment: @oliholz Yup, changed the JRE to 6, set the compiler compliance level to 1.6, did a full system rebuild, restarted eclipse...still no luck :/

Answer (score 3):

You should use a [Swing Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) with a delay, instead of using your own Thread and Runnable for this.

> You can use Swing timers in two ways:
>
> - To perform a task once, after a delay. 
>     For example, the tool tip manager uses Swing timers to determine when to show a tool tip and when to hide it.
> - To perform a task repeatedly. 
>     For example, you might perform animation or update a component that displays progress toward a goal.

An example from the documentation:

```
  int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          //...Perform a task...
      }
  };
  Timer myTimer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
  myTimer.setRepeats(false);
  myTimer.start();
```

Comment: This isn't a bad method, just not exactly what I need as the length of time it takes to complete the FileConverter is highly variable and thus a pre-defined timer wouldn't be the best option for me. But thank you though.